# Load php function with AJAX on modal window

Tags: php, ajax, javascript

On a movie information wordpress theme i am developing, i have an href with text "watch trailer" on each cover of all movies. This brings a modal window, and that is working already, but i want to bring the trailer of the movie onclick, without having to reload the page.

For testing purposes and to ask for help here, i've made a loop that will obtain the data necessary for this "info" href for only one movie.

(head.php has the ajax library in it)

Get.php:

```
<?php include 'head.php' ?>
<script>
function trailerProcess(){
    $.ajax({
            url:   'sendTrailer.php',
            type:  'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".trailerPadding").html("Processing, wait please...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                    $(".trailerPadding").html(response);
            }
    });
}
</script>
<?php
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php'); 
?>
<?php $args = array('tag'=> 'newMovies', 'posts_per_page' => 1,); ?>
<?php query_posts( $args ); ?><?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="#modal<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" onClick="trailerProcess();" class="linkColorWhite">
<div class="botoninfo"><span>watch trailer</span></div>
</a>
<div id="modal<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="modalmask">
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
<span class="TrailerTitle">Trailer: <?php echo the_title(); ?></span>
<div class="trailerPadding">
<?php // Trailer should be shown here // ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

sendTrailer.php:

```
<?php require('../../../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("Trailer"); echo $values[0]; ?>
```

As outcome, i obtain a 404 error not found sendTrailer.php path on the ctrl+j chrome console. But if in sendTrailer.php i quit the `require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');` i get a php "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_post_custom_values..." displayed, so it finds the file, knowing that wp functions won't work.
But if i also quit the require function and write `<?php echo "hello" ?>`the whole code works and the "hello" gets displayed.
So, my conclusion is that the require function is causing this 404 error not found... why?
¿How can i work out this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I have replaced the wp-blog-header.php with load.php, the wordpress data now works and i get no "processing...", but it still doesn't get nor echoes the custom value of $values in sendTrailer.php.

Comment: This is totally not the way to do ajax in wordpress, you should read this - http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Well, at this point i only want to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly use `sendTrailer.php` ,wordpress can't find this custom page directly so you have to specify fully path of that page using

[get_template_directory()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)

In your ajax function write

```
url : '<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/sendTrailer.php'
```

Comment: Check the edit. Btw, the full url or the php template directory was giving the same result.